# How to compare 2 List<T> when T implements IEquatable?

Tags: c#, linq, equality

I have a class and implements `IEquatable`:

```
public class MyObject: IEquatable<MyObject>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(MyObject other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;

        return this.Name.Equals(other.Name);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, o)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, o)) return true;
        if (o.GetType() != GetType()) return false;

        return Equals(o as MyObject);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 29;
            hash = hash * 31 + Name != null ? Name.GetHashCode() : 0;
            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

To keep the example short, I just kept the `Name` property. The class has other properties though.

Now I have 2 lists (A, B) of `MyObject` and I want to get a list of items that are in A but missing in B.

How can I do this by using LINQ (preferably) and making sure that `IEquatable` is used (or Equals) is used?

Comment: Have you tried LINQ's `Except` method, putting a breakpoint inside your `Equals()` to see if it calls your Equals function?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: So what is your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Except`, it will use already your `IEquatable<MyObject>`:

```
IEnumerable<MyObject> missingInB = A.Except(B);
```

Note that the `Name` property should be readonly if it's used in `GetHashCode` to identify the object.

LINQ methods will use your overridden `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, either by implementing `IEquatable<T>` or just the inherited from `System.Object`. Another option:  pass a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151(v=vs.110).aspx) to [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) (or other LINQ methods) if you don't want to modify your class.

Comment: Well, yes. Your hash code can change along the way.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono: sure, if the object is in a collection that relies on a stable hashcode to find your object, like a dictionary. So in general you should avoid using mutable properties/fields as identifiers which are used in GetHashCode. MSDN mentions it also: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx _"A hash function must have the following properties: .... You can ensure that the hash code of a mutable object does not change while the object is contained in a collection that relies on its hash code...."_

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono Also, please note that your current code will crash if Name is null: use `string.Equals(Name, other.Name)` to compare strings when either of them might be null.